# iContact api subscribe contact to list

Tags: php, icontact

I'm trying to integrate iContact api with wordpress and I need to add/move/delete contacts in lists under certain circumstances. 
I can add contact with addContact() method. But when I'm trying to subscribe contact via `subscribeContactToList($iContactId, $iListId, $sStatus)` method, it doesn't work and returns me an emty array.

It seems I'm doing everything according to following example: https://github.com/icontact/icontact-api-php/blob/master/examples.php. I haven't any idea how can get it to work.

What am I doing wrong?
Has anyone faced with such problem and which is the most proper way to tackle it?

Here is my code:

```
// Load the iContact library
require_once('icontact/iContactApi.php');
// configuring iContact API
iContactApi::getInstance()->setConfig(array(
    'appId'       => '',
    'apiPassword' => '',
    'apiUsername' => ''
));
$oiContact = iContactApi::getInstance();
$contactInfo = $oiContact->addContact(
                        $user->user_email,
                        'normal',  
                        null, 
                        $first_name, 
                        $last_name, 
                        null, 
                        null, 
                        null, 
                        null, 
                        null, 
                        null, 
                        null, 
                        null, 
                        null
                    );
$oiContact->subscribeContactToList($contactInfo->contactId, $list_id, 'normal');
```

Comment: Hi Avag, Did you get it working?

Comment: Hi @sameerali, yes I did. I don't remember what was my problem.
Use [following](https://github.com/icontact/icontact-api-php) lib to make API calls, check out the examples, also make sure you have provided right credentials. Let me know if you have difficulties.

Comment: Hi @avag-sargsyan Thanks for your reply. I'm following the same API documentation, providing the correct credentials and list id, but it always returns me empty array.

Comment: @sameerali, if your code on localhost, try with live server.

Comment: I tried on live site but no luck, getting the same result.

Comment: @sameerali, maybe it will be useful to see your code.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible you have used invalid listID.

You can use the function `getLists()` to get correct ID.

`var_dump($oiContact->getLists());`

It normally returns nothing when invalid ID happen.